# Which is brighter, starlight or the CMB?

Tags: star, cosmic-microwave-background, apparent-magnitude

Which do we receive more energy from, the CMB or starlight? (Not including the sun of course.)

Comment: I take it that you want to exclude the light from one particular nearby Type-G star, the only one easily visible during the day?

Comment: On the ground, or from space? The atmosphere is more transparent to visible light than to microwaves. (And of course it also blocks a lot of the UV from stars).

Comment: Eg, from https://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/atm-absorption.htm This chart shows zenith attenuation https://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/images2/atmospheric-specific-attenuation-zenith-itu.gif The CMB peak is ~160 GHz.

Comment: An answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46838/how-many-percent-of-the-visible-light-reaching-the-earth-are-from-other-stars-th  says that the CMB is about twice as bright as the stars

Comment: The energy of the CMB dominates over starlight in the "cosmic background" — i.e. outside of the Milky Way — by an order of magnitude or more, as clarified in [this answer on physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/196373/70207). But if you mean here, on Earth, then starlight probably dominates.